# Convert timestamp to "YY/MM/DD" with JS

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, type-conversion

I need to convert my "80814.89999999851" timestamp to a YY/MM/DD string.
I started by doing this:

var prova = info.originalEvent.timeStamp; //this path lead to: 80814.89999999851

var prova2 = new Date(prova);

Now I have it as a datetime (if i'm not mistaken) but i don't know how to keep just the year/month/day and then convert it to a string.
Can someone help me?

Comment: In which format is your timestamp? Spontaneously I can not think of a time format where `80814.89999999851` make sense. Its not a valid unixtime or similar i know.

Comment: actually i don't know. I'm using fullcalendar and for various reason i'm not able to get the "info.startStr" or "info.event.startStr" (yy/mm/dd as a string) of the day selected. If i try on the console to print "info" i can see, under the "timeStamp" properties it has this value

Comment: Once you work out how to convert "80814.89999999851" to a *Date*, this is a duplicate of [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This timestamp is not seconds since unix epoch, its seconds since `timeOrigin` (most likely time since page was loaded), to convert it to date you need to obtain `timeOrigin` first. Take a look at this question: [Knowing the time origin of event's timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110394/knowing-the-time-origin-of-events-timestamp).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp